# Why Random Forest gives better results than XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, xgboost

I'm trying to compare accuracy results (on titanic dateset) between `random forest` and `XGBoost`, and I can't figure out why `random forest` gives better results.

- XGBoost is kind of optimized tree base model. It calculating optimized tree  every cycle (every new estimator).
- Random forest build many trees (with different data and different features) and select the best tree.

I'm working on titanic dateset (after I handle Nan and remove some noise). (Both models get the same dateset)

For both algorithms I'm tuning with hyper parameters.

XGBoost model:

```
model = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)
hyperparams = {'max_depth': [2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
               'n_estimators': [20, 50, 100, 120],
               'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]}

randomized = RandomizedSearchCV(model, hyperparams, n_iter=40, cv=5, random_state=42, scoring='accuracy')
randomized.fit(x,y)
best_params = randomized.best_estimator_
model = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1,
                                   max_depth=best_params.max_depth,
                                   n_estimators=best_params.n_estimators,
                                   learning_rate=best_params.learning_rate)
model.fit(train_df_x, train_df_y)
y_pred = model.predict(test_df_x)
```

Random forest model:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
hyperparams = {'n_estimators': [20, 50, 100, 120],
                'max_depth': [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}

randomized = RandomizedSearchCV(model, hyperparams, n_iter=20, cv=5, random_state=42, scoring='accuracy')
randomized.fit(x, y)
best_params = randomized.best_estimator_
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42,
                                            n_jobs=-1,
                                            n_estimators=best_params.n_estimators,
                                            max_depth=best_params.max_depth)
model.fit(train_df_x, train_df_y)
y_pred = model.predict(test_df_x)
```

As you can see:

- I'm using more iterations of hyper parameters on `XGBoost` (because it has more parameters to tune).

I'm getting the following accuracy results:

- Random forest: 86.6
- XGBoost: 85.41

Before running the test, I was sure that XGBoost will give me better results.

How can it be that `random forest` give better results ? What am I missing when using `XGBoost` ?

Comment: RF is a very powerful classifier *in general*. The fact that XGBoost *usually* performs better is of empirical and statistical nature, and does not justify your surprise here; at the end of the day, much depends on the particular dataset.

Comment: The titanic dataset is small. Maybe if you will have much more data, then you will get better results with Xgboost. But it very much depends on the data ...